# RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v11.3

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5, python-sip

I recently installed PyQt4 onto my system and started doing some basic tasks (course work), it worked fine.

Then, after some days, I was trying to work with `matplotlib`.

When I tried `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`,I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Confusion.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 58, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 127, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v11.3
[Finished in 1.9s]
```

I thought that the problem is with the installation of `PyQt4` while I already had `PyQt5`, but [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html)website says that they can work properly together without any problem, provided the `sip` is of same version for both.

The problem seems to be coming from `sip`.

I followed the steps given here : [PyQt5 - SIP API 10 level error. API 11 required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22896854/3564318)

1. When I run `import sip` and then
   `print(sip, sip.SIP_VERSION_STR)`

   I get the following:

   4.16.9
2. Then when I run `sip -V` in the command prompt, I get `4.18`.

I clearly see that there is in the `sip` module.

All I want to ask is, how do I solve this problem?

**I am on a Windows 8 64 bit system, using Anaconda3**

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved by doing a `pip install pyqt5` and the `sip` version became same.

I followed this website : [PyQt Sourceforge](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ehi Pragyaditya! pip install pyqt5 does not work for me. Can you imagine why? I have python 2.7.11

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? And also consider asking a fresh question; notify me here. I will do my best to answer.

Answer (score 7):

You have to update the [PyQt5-sip](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-sip/) package as well:

```
pip install PyQt5-sip --upgrade
```

Comment: This works!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and upgrading sip through conda worked for me:

```
conda upgrade sip
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And I fixed it temporarily by :
try `import PyQt4` or `import PyQt5` before `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`