# how to install QtSvg,QtWebKit,QtWebKitWidgets(all in Qt5 version) on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, qt, qt5

I want to install eric6-6.0.6.The result of

```
python3 install.py
```

is:

```
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.4.0
Found PyQt5
Found QScintilla2
Found QtGui
Found QtNetwork
Found QtPrintSupport
Found QtSql
Sorry, please install QtSvg.
Error: No module named 'PyQt5.QtSvg'
Sorry, please install QtWebKit.
Error: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'
Sorry, please install QtWebKitWidgets.
Error: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
Found QtWidgets
```

But how to install the missing?
I google a lot but fail to find the correct answer.

Anyone could do me a favor?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you installed `Qt`?

Answer (score 13):

You can install these packages all with

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

I don't have an ubuntu distro set up right now, so I can't verify for you, but I don't think you'll need to install the third package.

Packages:

[libqt5webkit5-dev](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libqt5webkit5-dev)

For python-3.x:

[python3-pyqt5.qtsvg](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/python3-pyqt5.qtsvg)

[python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit)

Comment: If I install these packages,I will change the sip package,then I will met the following problem while install eric6:
including the following traceback, to eric-bugs@eric-ide.python-projects.org.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 1548, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "install.py", line 1451, in main
    doDependancyChecks()
  File "install.py", line 1077, in doDependancyChecks
    from PyQt5 import Qsci      # __IGNORE_WARNING__
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 but the PyQt5.Qsci module requires API v11.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569388/cant-import-modules-in-python-pyqt4-conflicts-with-sip

What OS are you running?