# Python - Using Qt5 to build a simple web browser

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I was trying to build this example:

https://www.linuxvoice.com/build-a-web-browser-with-20-lines-of-python/

I'll just repost it here for completeness:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView 
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
view = QWebView() 
view.show() 
view.setUrl(QUrl(“http://linuxvoice.com”)) 
app.exec()
```

I also used the indications here to install pyqt5

https://askubuntu.com/questions/612314/how-to-install-pyqt-for-python3-in-ubunt-14-10

and also installed Qt5. So I should have everything they say in the linuxvoice tutorial.

When I want to run this with python 2.7, it says:

```
 File "brows.py", line 9 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file brows.py on line 9, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

and with Python3:

```
File "brows.py", line 9
view.setUrl(QUrl(“http://linuxvoice.com”)) 
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Did anyone manage to make this work?

Comment: SOLVED: Basically I was missing these packages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734287/how-to-install-qtsvg-qtwebkit-qtwebkitwidgetsall-in-qt5-version-on-ubuntu-14-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO here's the actual answer.  I had the same issue and discovered it very fast.
`view.setUrl(QUrl(“http://linuxvoice.com”))`
Notice that their code uses quotes, look at how the quotes are compared to normal quotes.

Normal: ""

Theirs: “”

Basically, they're using weird ASCII quotes that Python can't handle. Really sneaky way to prevent copy-pasters. 
Either way this code doesn't work anymore because in the most recent version of PyQt5, `QtWebKitWidgets` was removed.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a stray byte somewhere in your code. It's popped up on StackOverflow previously and there's a good method for finding it: [Python "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file).

Comment: So I solve that, now both of them point to the http saying invalid character in identifier.

Comment: Did you copy the code from elsewhere? If so it might have hidden webformatting bytes, try just deleting the line and recoding it from scratch.

Comment: I rewrote everything. I still get:    File "brows.py", line 10
    app.exec()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Qubix. You need to use `app.exec_()` in pyqt, because `exec` is a keyword in python2. The non-ascii characters are the left/right double quotation marks (`“”`), which are often used in web pages rather than the standard double quotes (`"`).